# Getting fatal error when trying to install Umami test site

Tags: 10

I'm using Windows 10. I have installed composer and PHP.

I run the command `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project mysite` to create a recommended project. That works with no errors. Then I try to run the command `php web/core/scripts/drupal quick-start demo_umami` to install a sample Drupal site using the Umami Maganize demo:

```
C:\drupal\mysite>php web/core/scripts/drupal quick-start demo_umami
 9/17 [==============>-------------]
Install site
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 
bytes) in C:\drupal\mysite\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\ItemList.php on 
line 274

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) 
in C:\drupal\mysite\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\TypedData\Plugin\DataType\ItemList.php on line 
274

C:\drupal\mysite>
```

It makes no sense that I'm trying to allocate only 20480 bytes and that's causing it to throw a FatalError. How do I fix this?

Comment: That's trying to allocate 20480 bytes ontop of what's already allocated to the php task

Comment: Well I raised the memory_limit in php.ini from 128M to 2G and tried it again, and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a bit like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. For this very narrow requirement, it appears to have done the job. But at what hidden cost to the underlying structure of your nut-bashing table

Answer (score -3):

In php.ini, increase the memory_limit from 128MB to 2G:

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
; https://php.net/memory-limit
;memory_limit = 128M
memory_limit = 2G
```